# Receive Custom FCM In Unity

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging

I integrated Firebase Cloud Messaging with Unity successfully and I can receive usual messages when I send them from Firebase Console, but I need some extra things.

1 - How can I send my notification as a URL? I mean I want that when user touches the notification it opens the URL that I put in the value in FireBase Console.

2 - How I can send and show a picture and a custom icon in the notification?

Unfortunately, I can't find anything on the internet and official documents confused me.

Is there any way to gain these request only with FireBase SDK?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle all the messages from FCM manually to get all those features you are looking for. I mean you got the general implementation all the stuff, but you need the unique one. All the notification display settings and notification click handlers have to be implemented on the Android native side.

Probably you will find some interesting FCM asset in the Asset Store with nice notifications customization, not sure. But I would recommend you to surf the Asset Store, maybe there will be some useful packages.